# Showing all errors and warnings

Tags: php, debugging, warnings

**UPDATE 2:**

I have now removed the following from the .php file:

```
<?php error_reporting( E_ALL ); ?>
```

I have set display_erros in php.ini as follows:

> display_errors = On

Error reporting is set to the following in `php.ini`:

> error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

After restarting Apache, I still get no errors/warnings.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have changed error_reporting in `php.ini` from:

> error_reporting = E_ALL &
>   ~E_DEPRECATED

to

> error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

After which I restarted Apache, e.g.

> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

But the page will still not display errors/warnings of any kind.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

The following script is generating a warning because the $err being inside the if statement. Why is this warning not being displayed on the PHP page in a web browser?

I have to look at the Apache logs to see the warning.  Also, if I deliberately change the "insert into" to "delete into", it does not display an error on the PHP page. Why are the errors not displaying on the actual PHP page?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">

        <?php
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                $err = array();

                if (empty( $_POST['display_name']))
                    $err[] = "display name field is required";
                if (empty( $_POST['email']))
                    $err[] = "email field is required";
                if (empty( $_POST['password']))
                    $err[] = "password field is required";

                if (!$err) {
                    try {
                        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1", "user", "pass");
                        $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                        $STH = $DBH->prepare("delete into table1 (display_name, email, password) values ( :display_name, :email, :password )");

                        $STH->bindParam(':display_name', $_POST['display_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
                        $STH->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
                        $STH->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

                        $STH->execute();

                        $STH = $DBH->prepare("delete into table2 ( username, status, users_id ) values ( :username, :status, :users_id )");

                        $strStatus = 1;

                        $STH->bindParam(':username', $_POST['display_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
                        $STH->bindParam(':status', $strStatus, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1);
                        $STH->bindParam(':users_id', $_POST['referer'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 1);

                        $STH->execute();

                        $DBH = null;
                    }
                    catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }

                    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                    exit;
                }
                else {
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
                        $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $form['display_name'] = $form['email'] = $form['password'] = '';
            }
        ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php foreach($err as $line) { ?>
        <div style="error"><?php echo $line; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <h1>Register</h1>

        <form method="post">
            Referers id:<br/>
            <input type="text" name="referer" /><br/><br/>

            Name:<br/>
            <input type="text" name="display_name" value="<?php echo $form['display_name']; ?>" /><br/><br/>

            Email:<br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $form['email']; ?>" /><br/><br/>

            Password:<br/>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $form['password']; ?>" /><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the current value of the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/display_errors) INI setting?

Comment: I've just check and it is set to error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: Please re-read my question, we already know your `error_reporting` setting because it is in the script.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 1:** in the original question.

Comment: Please re-re-read my question. `display_errors` is entirely different from `error_reporting`. Also, your script overrides the `error_reporting` value set in the INI file.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 2:** in the original question.

Comment: Try a sample script like http://codepad.viper-7.com/lEm5Vx and see if that displays any errors.

Comment: Who else is not upvoting because he has 420 upvotes?

Answer (score 1306, accepted):

Display errors could be turned off in the `php.ini` or your Apache configuration file.

You can turn it on in the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You should see the same messages in the PHP error log.

Comment: Do I need to restart apache after changing the php.ini file?

Comment: already this question has been posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @oshirowanen `ini_set()` does not actually change the `php.ini` file, the script only "acts" like it is set like that in `php.ini`... **From manual:** `Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value ` *`during the script's execution`* `, and ` **`will be restored at the script's ending`** `.`

Comment: I don't know how many times I came to same answer. You helped me a lot. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Charles Why would `E_ALL` remove `E_NOTICE`? Doesn't E_ALL by itself including everything, including E_NOTICE?

Comment: @NickRolando It doesn't. My original answer removed E_NOTICE messages. Charles took me to task and I edited the answer.

Comment: the only way to show parser errors is to edit the php.ini file. ini_set will not work.

Comment: I always do development in production so is it good idea to turn on E_ALL but disable display errors, it will still log them in error_log right?

Comment: @txyoji of course Nick is right. `E_ALL` does include `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: For those who are in doubt, it is not necessary to restart apache

Comment: The values for `ini_set` should actually be strings, such as `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` as per [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/function.ini-set) and this is **enforced** when using [strict typing](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) (eg, `declare(strict_types=1);`)  ...though the fact that nobody else has pointed this out tells me that nobody uses strict typing!

Comment: In 2011 strict typing wasn't a thing for php. Thanks for the update @ashleedawg.

Answer (score 70):

I was able to get all errors via the below code:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: only code that worked for me on my server (IONOS)

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);` should not be used. It may not work on every system. Instead should be `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: error_reporting(-1) should work just fine as it is given as example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The values for `ini_set` should actually be strings, such as `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` as per [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/function.ini-set) and this is **enforced** when using [strict typing](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) (eg, `declare(strict_types=1);`)

Answer (score 48):

PHP errors can be displayed by any of below methods:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For more details:

*[Displaying PHP errors](http://www.howtofindit.in/displaying-php-errors/)*

Comment: The `display_errors = on;` in PHP file has `syntax error`.

Answer (score 42):

Straight from the *php.ini* file:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; This directive informs PHP of which errors, warnings and notices you would like
; it to take action for. The recommended way of setting values for this
; directive is through the use of the error level constants and bitwise
; operators. The error level constants are below here for convenience as well as
; some common settings and their meanings.
; By default, PHP is set to take action on all errors, notices and warnings EXCEPT
; those related to E_NOTICE and E_STRICT, which together cover best practices and
; recommended coding standards in PHP. For performance reasons, this is the
; recommend error reporting setting. Your production server shouldn't be wasting
; resources complaining about best practices and coding standards. That's what
; development servers and development settings are for.
; Note: The php.ini-development file has this setting as E_ALL. This
; means it pretty much reports everything which is exactly what you want during
; development and early testing.
;
; Error Level Constants:
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (includes E_STRICT as of PHP 5.4.0)
; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
; E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  - almost fatal run-time errors
; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
;                     relying on the fact it is automatically initialized to an
;                     empty string)
; E_STRICT          - run-time notices, enable to have PHP suggest changes
;                     to your code which will ensure the best interoperability
;                     and forward compatibility of your code
; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
;                     initial startup
; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
; E_DEPRECATED      - warn about code that will not work in future versions
;                     of PHP
; E_USER_DEPRECATED - user-generated deprecation warnings
;
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
; Development Value: E_ALL
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

For pure development I go for:

```
    error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING
```

Also don't forget to put display_errors to on

```
display_errors = On
```

After that, restart your server for Apache on Ubuntu:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: "PHP 6.0.0"? Heh :-)

Comment: “For pure development @JohnMagnolia go[es] for:
`error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING`.” Are the `^` symbols concatenating the three options? If so, doesn’t `E_ALL` already include `E_NOTICE` and `E_WARNING`?

Answer (score 11):

Set these on `php.ini`:

```
;display_startup_errors = On
display_startup_errors=off
display_errors =on
html_errors= on
```

From your PHP page, use a suitable filter for error reporting.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Filers can be made according to requirements.

```
E_ALL
E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Answer (score 7):

You can see a detailed description [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

> ### Changelog

- > 5.4.0    E_STRICT became part of E_ALL
- > 5.3.0    E_DEPRECATED and E_USER_DEPRECATED introduced.
- > 5.2.0    E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR introduced.
- > 5.0.0    E_STRICT introduced (not part of E_ALL).